# how to create data frames in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames below `df1` and `df2`.I would like to create three data frames based on scenarios listed in `df2`. So for instance, `df3` which is based on scenario1 from `df2` will be to `add` `10` to `cover` which is all a`(a1,a2,a3)` in `df1`.

```
 df1                        
 No a1  a2  a3  b1  b2  b3
 3  7   1   3   2   1   7
 3  9   4   9   7   6   2
 3  8   3   1   3   5   0

df2         
Scenario  Cover Action   Number
 1           a   Add        10
 2           a   Subtract   7
 3           b   Multiply   2

df3         
No  Scenario1a1 Scenario1a2 Scenario1a3
3      17         11          13
3      19         14          19
3      18         13          11

df4         
No  Scenario2a1 Scenario2a2 Scenario2a3
3        0        -6         -4
3        2        -3          2
3        1        -4         -6

df5         
No  Scenario3b1 Scenario3b2 Scenario3b3
3        3        2           15
3        14       12           3
3        6        10           0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function takes one line from `df2` as first argument and `df1` as second argument.

```
apply.line <- function(line, df)
{
    operators <- list(Add=function(x,y) x+y, 
                      Subtract=function(x,y) x-y, 
                      Multiply=function(x,y) x*y)

    ret <- operators[[line$Action]](df[grepl(line$Cover, names(df))], line$Number)
    names(ret) <- eval(call("paste0", "Scenario", line$Scenario, names(ret)))
    ret
}
```

Usage:

```
df3 <- apply.line(df2[1,], df1)
df4 <- apply.line(df2[2,], df2)
df5 <- apply.line(df2[3,], df3)
```

Comment: Thanks how would the code change if i need to another function `New` like `New=function(x,y,l) min(x+y,l)`

Comment: Provided that ```l``` is a constant just add it to the operator list.

Answer (score 0):

Manually, you can just do the following: (I just used another example)

```
df1<-array(c(1:21), dim=c(3,7))

df3<-df1+10
df4<-df1-7
df5<-df1*2
```